# Optimal way to get last posts of user's friends in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my DB each user has friends. And I need to get 50 *last* posts of the user's friends. See below structure of posts of each user in Firebase DB.

So what is optimal way to do that? If a user has for example 150 friends, then my Android app should have as many listeners as friends. Is it ok to have 150 or more DB listeners in the app? Also what is the way to get all friends' posts in single query? Thanks.

```
root
- posts
  - {userUid}
    - {postUid}
      - text
      - dateCreated
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have as many listeners as you want with the condition to remove them according to your life-cycle of your activity. But in your case, you don't need 150 listeners, you only need just one. Assuming that the node under the user is is named `friends`, you can attach a single listener on `friends` node and then iterate over the `DataSnapshot` object using `getChildren()` method. Assuming that your database looks simmilar with this:

```
Firebase-root
  |
  --- users
       |
       --- uid1
            |
            --- friends
                  |
                  --- friendId1: true
                  |
                  --- friendId2: true
```

To get all the friends that corespond to a particular user, please use the following code:

```
String uid = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference friendsRef = rootRef.child("users").child(uid).child(friends);
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String friendId = ds.getKey();
            Log.d("TAG", friendId);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
friendsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

To get all post that of all users, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference postsRef = rootRef.child("posts");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String uid = ds.getKey();

            DatabaseReference uidRef = postsRef.child(uid);
            ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot dSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String text = dSnapshot.child("text").getValue(String.class);
                        long dateCreated = dSnapshot.child("dateCreated").getValue(Long.class);
                        Log.d("TAG", text + " / " + dateCreated)
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
            };
            uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
postsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Comment: I don't need just get user's friends, instead I should get their last posts (see the question)

Comment: Thanks, but your update is about getting post of single user. So still I have to use 150 listeners to get all posts.

Comment: Please see again my updated answer. In this scenario you need to use only 2 listeners and not 150. It's ok now?

Comment: I do not need get all users' post, it is very redundantly. Imagine you have 1M users with variety count of posts for each user. A user has 150 friends, so I shouldn't scan all (1M) users to get their posts, obviously.

Comment: There is no other way using this database structure to get that data. There is also no way for geeting this in a single query. Try to make a separate section in which you can add only the desired data and then query your database just once. This is a common practice within Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is have a friendsListener, once initialized I would loop through my friends and register their reference in my listener vs 150 listeners.

Comment: In this case you should have index with posts of friends for each user. This looks redundantly.

Answer (score 0):

You can have 150+ listeners but the less the better. Maybe you can just watch all posts instead of listening to every friend separtely.

To get all posts of a friend **once** try:

```
ref('posts').child(friendUid).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
   console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

To get the last 50 posts of a friend **once** try:

```
ref('posts').child(friendUid).orderByChild("dateCreated").limitToLast(50).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
   console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

(depending on your dateCreated property you might need to use limitToFirst instead of limitToLast. Check the [Firebase Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query) docu for more information.)

Comment: It is simple to get the last posts of a user, but in my case I should get posts from different users

Comment: Okay my bad then. The friend/user relation in your db structure obviously wasn't clear enough for me ;) I'm afraid you have to check every friend separately. I don't think theres a way to do this in only one query.